# How do I add API keys and other secure stuff to heroku?

Tags: github, heroku

I read somewhere but cannot seem to find where to add secret keys into Heroku without needing to put it into the source code git repository?

I guess that helps keep it secure when I am pushing into github.

How do I do that and does that make sense to do?

Answer (score 5):

As Mark has suggested, the best way would be Heroku environment vars. you can read about them [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars):

To do so, you need to use [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) which you need to download and install it based on your operating system. Don't forget to set up Heroku CLI with these 3 steps:

`$ heroku login
 $ cd ~/myapp
 $ heroku create (your Heroku app name)`

now it's time to set up config variable. The command is:

```
$ heroku config:set <ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE>=<VALUE>
```

for example I'm gonna save my API key here as a config var:

```
$ heroku config:set DARKSKY_API_KEY=8e11111111162218d22222222229cc22222c6
```

and now it's time to use it in you server side code. For Nodejs you can access them by:

```
process.env.DARKSKY_API_KEY
```

like so:

```
  const weatherURL =`https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${process.env.DARKSKY_API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}?units=si`;
```

For other languages like Ruby, Java, ... check this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#accessing-config-var-values-from-code).

you can view your config vars by typing:

```
$ heroku config
```

or removing a config var:

```
$ heroku config:unset DARKSKY_API_KEY
```

Also, I was thinking about a .env file for heroku config vars that we can edit them locally and then upload them on heroku. Finally, I come up with this solution.

To save the cofig vars locally from heroku and be able to change them locally in a file, later down the road when it's needed, we can run:

```
$ heroku config | sed 's/: */=/g; /^=/d' >> HEROKU_CONFIG_ENV.env
```

which `HEROKU_CONFIG_ENV.env` is just a file name and you can name whatever you like.This script is gonna save `HEROKU_CONFIG_ENV.env` file on the root of your project.

After modifying the keys, it's the time to upload them on Heroku and set heroku config vars by running:

```
$ heroku config:set $(cat HEROKU_CONFIG_ENV.env | sed '/^$/d; /#[[:print:]]*$/d')
```

that's it.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars

Then add the development keys to an initializer:

```
#config/initializers/keys.rb

development:
  SOME_KEY = 'abc123' #not your production key

testing:
  SOME_KEY = 'abc123' #not your production key

#production:
  #blank
```

Optionally add the initializer to .gitignore. Not required as your production key isn't stored.

Comment: super-- I don't quite understand how to then store them on my local windows machine to use in development...?  Do you know?